# Can I use the on-camera flash along with an off-camera SB-700 on my Nikon D5000?

Tags: off-camera-flash, nikon-d5000, strobist, ttl, sb-700

I recently bought an SB-700 flash for my D5000 and I was wondering what would be my options to use this as an off-camera flash **along** with the on-camera flash.

Is it possible? TTL cable, wireless transmitter, whatever...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, using the on-camera-flash in manual power setting and the SB-700 in SU-4 optical slave mode.

Comment: finally found out how; also helpful as for how to get it done : http://forums.dpreview.com/forums/thread/3067352